# Axiom of choice where there are very few choices?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

My apologies if this question has already been answered in the mathematical literature, but I am not a set theorist and this merely crossed my mind while I was studying measure theory.

The axiom of choice asserts that for any family of sets $F_i$ where $i\in\beta$ there exists at least one function $f:\beta\to\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in\beta}F_i$ such that $f(x)\in F_x$ for all $x\in\beta$.

My question is this: in ZFC what do we know about the number of choice functions you can have?

For example, is ZFC consistent with the existence of an example where $\beta$ and $F_i$ are all infinite and where there are only countably many such choice functions?

Comment: An important result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  There is a choice function $\tilde f$ that selects a two-element subset from each $F_i$.  Let $f: \beta \to \cup F_i$ be a choice function that selects from each subset; i.e., $f(i) \in \tilde f(F_i)$.  For each subset of $B \subseteq \beta$ there's a choice function $g$ with $g(i) \in \tilde f(F_i)$ that agrees with $f$ exactly on $B$, so there are at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ choice functions.